# Codeigniter can't remove index from url

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos

I am Using CentOS,

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|resources)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteBase /var/www/html/site/

</IfModule>
```

but geting same problem my pages with index.php works fine but when i remove index.php
it's not working...

Comment: Is 'WWW' your sites root folder?

Comment: your rewritebase is wrong, it is relative to the document root

if your doc root is /var/www/html/ your rewritebase should be /site

Comment: @ikhsan yes I was going the same way, it won't work if that is not correct

Comment: i just change my httpd.conf (AllowOverride None) to (AllowOverrid All) and restart it worked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it will help you as i am using this one.Put this code in your root folder's htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Please let me know if it is working or not.

Comment: I had this in my .htaccess example too. don't know why it did not work for you. glad you found a fix.

Comment: I know. look at my answer. I'm not having problems using .htaccess.

Answer (score 2):

This can be a few things.

1( remove the index page from your config file (application/config/config.php)

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

2( Do you have base_url like this:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://yourdomain.com/';
```

Note the `/` at the end.

3( try this .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^LoginTut.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|table-images|js|robots\.txt|css|captcha)

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
 ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: i have tried same as ur instruction but stell when i want my page with out the index.php it takes me to the google, not working

Comment: What is your site? can I look at it?

Comment: Aren't you running localhost, and Safari?

Comment: sorry dear Kees i am working on local so can't but if you have time i can give you google remote..

Comment: Could you try to rename your `.htaccess` to `.htaccess.txt` this should work locally. Don't forget to restart your apache server.

Comment: i did remove my htaccess and restart apache not working agian

Comment: do not remove it. rename it to .htaccess.txt and then restart. Use the code I gave you for the .htaccess

Comment: yes i did so same code and to name of .htaccess.txt and restarted httpd not working again

Comment: how did you restart your apache? turned it off at services and turned on again?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32268/discussion-between-welcome-always-and-kees-sonnema)

Answer (score 0):

Simple at your `config.php` file at your `config` folder search for index url (index_page) and make it empty

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: $config['index_page'] = '';   this is such and my .htaccess is as i have writen on my question..

Answer (score 0):

Try this it works for me ccnd is my files folder.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|uploads|images|css|js|lib|img|bootstrap|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ccnd/index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /site_root/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Important:
1. you must set `$config['index_page'] = '';` in config.php file.
2. site_root is folder name like, wamp/www/site_root.