# Navigation with Codeigneter Framework

Tags: php

Basicly I have a contreller that named site.php , and have views:header.php,nav.php,content.php,footer.php etc. problem is how can run content_about.php?
Im trying this url:site/about but I get an error on browser!
Code is that:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class site extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->home();
    }
    public function home()
    {
        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("site_nav");
        $this->load->view("content_home");
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }
    public function about()
    {
        $this->load->view("site_header");
        $this->load->view("site_nav");
        $this->load->view("content_about");
        $this->load->view("site_footer");
    }
}
```

Comment: what error ? code looks fine

Comment: error is 'the requested URL /basicsite/about was not found on this server.'

Comment: The url you have provided above is referring to the controller `basicsite`. Make sure that your filename is also `basicsite.php` and not `site.php`

Answer (score 2):

Try this one.

```
public function about()
{
    $data=array();
    $data['main']='content_about'; //only the content part without header,nav and footer
    $this->load->view('template',$data);
}
```

in view make template.php and put this lines

```
<?=$this->load->view('site_header.php');?>
<?=$this->load->view('site_nav.php');?>
<?=$this->load->view($main);?>
<?=$this->load->view('site_footer');?>
```

please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: Thank you but,it doesnt work again.What I'm missing? htacces file includes 'deny from all' in it.This cause that problem?

Comment: the following link may help you answered by me.please let me know the sattus after using it.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17273291/codeigniter-cant-remove-index-from-url/17273705#17273705